# My website displays perfectly in all browsers but IE any suggestions?

Tags: internet-explorer, validation, internet-explorer-8, web, cross-browser

I have built a website using wordpress that displays fine in all browsers except IE (surprise surprise). I'm currently using VirtualBox to try to sort it out but the page is so completely borked I'm not even sure where to start.

**Running a validator gives me the following errors:**

Line 2, Column 91: "LANG" is not a reserved name
…ttp://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" lang="en-US" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#…

Error Line 2, Column 91: cannot continue because of previous errors
…ttp://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" lang="en-US" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#…

**Here's the relevant code via the site's theme editor:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
```

Due to the weirdness of the problem I'm not even sure if this is the real issue. Why does microsoft hate us?!

--- EDIT ---
I failed to mention the web address which is [www.SleepHug.com](http://www.SleepHug.com)

**Here is the full header code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />

    <?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" title="<?php printf( __( '%s latest posts', '' ), wp_specialchars( get_bloginfo('name'), 1 ) ); ?>" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="<?php bloginfo('comments_rss2_url') ?>" title="<?php printf( __( '%s latest comments', '' ), wp_specialchars( get_bloginfo('name'), 1 ) ); ?>" />
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

<!-- Place this snippet wherever appropriate -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var li = document.createElement('script'); li.type = 'text/javascript'; li.async = true;
    li.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//platform.stumbleupon.com/1/widgets.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(li, s);
  })();
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var s = document.createElement('SCRIPT'), s1 = document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0];
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.async = true;
s.src = 'http://widgets.digg.com/buttons.js';
s1.parentNode.insertBefore(s, s1);
})();
</script>

<script src="//svpply.com/api/all.js#xsvml=1" type="text/javascript" ></script>


</head>
```

Comment: I think you should post more code. The doctype doesn't give us that much.

Comment: @DaveChen Sorry about that, I've added more code and link to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Your site is completely missing the html tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
</html>
```

Also, you have a blank line above your DOCTYPE, which triggers "quirks mode" in Internet Explorer.

More information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode and here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

**UPDATE:**

Change this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage SleepHug
 */
?><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
```

To this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
```

In fact, unless you specifically need HTML 4.01, you can even do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
```

And don't forget to add the closing `</html>` in your footer.php file.

Comment: When I use inspect element in both chrome and firefox the html tags are appearing correctly in place. I believe Wordpress inserts that automatically if I'm not mistaken. I'm not seeing a blankline above the doctype. `<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage SleepHug
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>`

Comment: You need to view the actual source code. Try this in your address bar: view-source:http://sleephug.com/ If the problem is in Internet Explorer, then it doesn't matter that Firefox and Chrome display correctly. Different browsers have varying levels of forgiveness.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3a04a020c085771706c9
This is how the code is formatted in my header theme. I haven't left any blank lines above the doctype that I'm aware of.

Comment: You're still missing the wrapping "html" tags. For example: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><?php wp_head(); ?></head>

Comment: You can also get rid of the package declaration comment at the top of your header.php file. That's what's causing the blank line. You should be sure to look at what's being rendered by your code. Pull this out, you don't need it: <?php
/**
 * package WordPress
 * subpackage SleepHug
 */
?>

Comment: Ok I fixed that problem, there was a space in one of the separate template pages and I added an html tag, however IE is still no better.

Comment: You still have the extra line at the top, and you haven't added the html wrapping tags. Perhaps I wasn't clear. I've updated my answer with your code modified appropriately.

Comment: I appreciate your patience and made the advised changes except for the doctype removal, I'd prefer to keep the strict setting. It looks like IE is still going haywire and W3C validator is reporting the same "lang" error

Comment: Unless you specifically need HTML 4 there's no reason to go with that specific DOCTYPE. http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: Ok I changed to XHTML 1.0. Now that I've done that I need to go thru and double check that my code is properly written then retest on the validator. I probably won't have anymore updates for the night while I chip away at this. Thanks again!

Comment: Update: I switched to HTML5. IE8 still going crazy. My site begins to load somewhat correctly (things are still out of place but its better than it was) - then there's multiple clicking noises then the css gets stripped resulting in the same broken appearing site I've been struggling with. No problems at all in any other browser and I still have no clue what the issue is, I've never encountered this.

Comment: IE8 looks fine to me, but IE7 doesn't; there are a lot of issues. You're just going to have to fix them one by one. Some things I saw: Your font-declarations are wrong (try this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/), you have some z-index issues (e.g., the logo), height/overflow problems, etc. Just try focusing on one thing at a time.